# Duplicate Ids in kmeans clustering

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a dataset of an ecommerce store that contains orders made within a month. One customer could have multiple records in the dataset, as expected. When I performed kmeans using python, the resulting clusters were overlapping by the customers that made multiple orders, but to different products. The problem is I want to provide recommendations for each customer, but I cannot determine which cluster to pick for such customers.

Thanks in Advance

```
# K-Means Clustering

# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder,OneHotEncoder

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('FYP.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, [10]].values
Y=dataset.iloc[:, [9]].values
Z=dataset.iloc[:,[5]].values

#The First Way Using LabelEncoder to change categorical values to numerical ones
labelencoder_X = LabelEncoder()
X=labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:,0])
labelencoder_Y = LabelEncoder()
Y=labelencoder_Y.fit_transform(Y[:,0])

done = np.vstack((Y,X)).T
done = np.column_stack((Z,Y,X))

#The Second Way
onehotencoder_done = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features="all")
done = onehotencoder_done.fit_transform(done).toarray()

#Then Applying PCA
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
done = pca.fit_transform(done)
explained_variance = pca.explained_variance_ratio_

# Using the elbow method to find the optimal number of clusters
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
wcss = []
for i in range(1, 11):
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = i, init = 'k-means++', max_iter = 1000, n_init = 10)
    kmeans.fit(done)
    wcss.append(kmeans.inertia_)
plt.plot(range(1, 11), wcss)
plt.title('The Elbow Method')
plt.xlabel('Number of clusters')
plt.ylabel('WCSS')
plt.show()

# Fitting K-Means to the dataset
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 3, init = 'k-means++', max_iter = 1000, n_init = 10)
y_kmeans = kmeans.fit_predict(done)



# Visualising the clusters
plt.scatter(done[y_kmeans == 0, 0], done[y_kmeans == 0, 1], s = 100, c = 'red', label = 'Cluster 1')
plt.scatter(done[y_kmeans == 1, 0], done[y_kmeans == 1, 1], s = 100, c = 'blue', label = 'Cluster 2')
plt.scatter(done[y_kmeans == 2, 0], done[y_kmeans == 2, 1], s = 100, c = 'green', label = 'Cluster 3')
plt.scatter(kmeans.cluster_centers_[:, 0], kmeans.cluster_centers_[:, 1], s = 300, c = 'yellow', label = 'Centroids')
plt.title('Clusters of customers')
plt.xlabel("Category")
plt.ylabel("Subcategory")
plt.show()
```

[Dataset Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJTBJ.png)

Comment: You're telling us your code doesn't do what you want, but you don't present the code. You're asking us to imagine what you have written, and then find the defect in it. You could begin by explaining what value you are clustering on.

Comment: @BoarGules I am very sorry. I thought I added them but here they are. X represents the product category column, Y represents the subcategory column, and Z represents the customer ID column.

Comment: K-means is a very poor choice for product recommendation. And this data is not suitable for kmeans either. Why would you use it?